# getting an element by the type and then disable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml

I am trying to get all elements inside of a div that are texboxes only. I have asp textboxes inside my div and also buttons

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="gameInfo">
    <asp:TextBox ID="gameTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="gameType" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="gameprice" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onClick="myFunc"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("wrapper").querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').disable = true;
}

</script>
```

Here I have tried to get all elements in `wrapper` and then do a queryselectall to get all inputs that equal text but it doesn't seem to be working I must be doing something wrong and also I would want this to happen as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) returns a nodelist of matching elements; my guess is that you'll have to loop through that array and disable each element individually:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("wrapper").querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
[].forEach.call(inputs, function(input){
    input.disabled = true;
});
```

Also note the double quotes in the selector query. `input[type=text] != input[type="text"]`

Comment: I should mention I haven't worked with ASP in a few years, so my answer is purely JS based

Comment: this doesn't seem to work I am trying it here in JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jtwq7jyj/

Comment: `input.disable` needs to be `input.disabled` - that should fix it for ya :) I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Asp outputs classic texbox element.So if you want to get the values just
loop through the input items inside the wrapper div and get the text values like:

```
for (x = 0; x < document.getElementById("wrapper").getElementsByTagName('input').length; x++) {    
    if (document.getElementById("wrapper").getElementsByTagName('input').item(x).type == 'text') {
        alert(document.getElementById("wrapper").getElementsByTagName('input').item(x).value);
    }
}
```

Playground here: http://jsfiddle.net/gkthgud8/

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, the OP wants to disable the input elements on pageload (and re-enable sets of them on a button-click)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have 2 typos:

- You are not executing `()` your onclick handler:

  ```
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onClick="myFunc"/>
  ```

  should have been:

  ```
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onClick="myFunc()"/>
  ```
- you misspelled `disabled`:

  ```
  .querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').disable = true;
  ```

  should have been:

  ```
  .querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').disabled = true;
  ```

---

Your question's title and javascript code in your question specifies you want to disable all input elements of type text in wrapper-div `wrapper` *on page-load*.

The button in your html-code is then used to enable (according to it's value and [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27151521/588079)) the inputs inside that specific div (like `gameInfo`).

Here is an example outlining how to do this *both* using *just one* enable/disable function (and without `querySelectorAll` (so you don't get an error in older older browsers that do not support it), in both cases you'd still loop through the elements):

```js
function disableInp(elm, true_false){
  for( var inputs = elm.getElementsByTagName('input'), L = inputs.length
     ; L-- // loop ends when L reaches 0
     ; inputs[L].type.toLowerCase()==='text' && (inputs[L].disabled = true_false)
     ); //end loop
}

window.onload=function(){
  disableInp(document.getElementById('wrapper'), true);
};
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- example html for live snippet -->
  <div class="gameInfo">
    <input type="text" maxLength="10" width="150px" />
    <input type="text" maxLength="10" width="150px" />
    <input type="text" maxLength="10" width="150px" />
    <input type="button" value="enable" 
        onclick="disableInp(this.parentNode, false)"/>
  </div>
  <div class="gameInfo"> <!-- extra row for example -->
    <input type="text" maxLength="10" width="150px" />
    <input type="text" maxLength="10" width="150px" />
    <input type="text" maxLength="10" width="150px" />
    <input type="button" value="enable" 
        onclick="disableInp(this.parentNode, false)"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to note that `id`'s inside HTML are supposed to be unique. Using a class is usually sufficient.

That should get you started!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper input").forEach((element) => { element.disabled = false; });
```

Comment: Can you add some context to the answer instead of posting code-only answer?