# getting the parent div of a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml

I am trying to get the parent div of the 'button1' and enable all the inputs in that div (I currently have them disabled'

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="gameInfo">
<asp:TextBox ID="gameTitle"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="gameType" />
<asp:TextBox ID="gameprice"/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onClick="myFunc()"/>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function myFunc() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var inputs = document.getElementById("button1").parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
                [].forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
                    input.disabled = false;
                });
            });
        }
```

I am trying to get the parent node of button1 and then I'm not really sure of the correct way of doing it but I want all the inputs in that parent div of the button to enable but only of the parent div of the button I clicked. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question, the (edited) code in your question works. (Why is there a setTimeout without a time set)?

Comment: are you sure you aren't getting any errors logged in the dev tools console (F12)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it a little different (without the setTimeout):

```js
function myFunc(elm){
   for( var inputs = elm.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')
      ,          L = inputs.length
      ; L--
      ; inputs[L].disabled = false  //enable inputs
      ); //end loop
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="gameInfo">
    <input type="text" ID="gameTitle" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ID="gameType" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ID="gameprice" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onclick="myFunc(this)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternative for browsers that don't support `querySelectorAll` (and optionally support `disabled`):

```js
function myFunc(elm){
   for( var inputs = elm.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')
      ,          L = inputs.length
      ; L--
      ; inputs[L].type.toLowerCase()==='text' && (inputs[L].disabled = false)
      ); //end loop
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="gameInfo">
    <input type="text" ID="gameTitle" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ID="gameType" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ID="gameprice" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onclick="myFunc(this)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea of both the above functions is that you pass the element that is clicked (the button) to the function: `onclick="myFunc(this)"`.
This will also work for multiple divs ('rows') without need to hardcode the `id`.

This should get you started!

Comment: works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/hjvkx04t/3/ (friendly hint: might be a good idea to read the manual of jsfiddle before using it...)

Comment: look, it also works for multiple divs: http://jsfiddle.net/hjvkx04t/6/ (just added some 'rows'). Is this what you are after?

Comment: Can you tell us what is not working for you instead of making us guess?

Comment: the code you sent what else do you think, when I click the button nothing happens

Comment: Did you 'Run code snippet' in my answer? Did you try: http://jsfiddle.net/hjvkx04t/3 and http://jsfiddle.net/hjvkx04t/6 and http://jsfiddle.net/hjvkx04t/8 ? Do you say that none of them work? All these work fine for me in FF, Chrome and Safari, even the code in your question works fine (and as such, also @Rhumborl's answer). What error are you getting (we can not guess this)? (I understand your frustration, but honey catches more flies..)

Comment: Im getting no error whenever I click the button nothing happens no error. But yes all the answers work fine in jsfiddle but only in jsfiddle

Comment: Then you should investigate the difference between what you are doing and the working jsfiddles/code snippets. Obviously, something is wrong in a part of code that you didn't share (and we can not know/guess that, I hope you understand that now). If you link me to a fiddle that does not work I'll have a quick look, but please, do try to keep that to the bare minimum of code that doesn't work.

Comment: I have investigated it works in jsfiddle dw I'll try sort it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just aren't calling myFunc correctly - you need brackets to actually *call* it:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onClick="myFunc()"/>
```

```js
function myFunc() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementById("button1").parentNode.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
      input.disabled = false;
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="another box" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="ignore me" />
  <div id="gameInfo">
    <input type="text" ID="gameTitle" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ID="gameType" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" ID="gameprice" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="enable" onClick="myFunc()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is just how you set your fiddle up - in the dropdown box on the left, change `onload` to `No wrap - in <body>` - http://jsfiddle.net/hjvkx04t/5/

Comment: oh ok, It doesn't work in my project solution is there something to do with no wrap i need to set in my project

Comment: no, as long as `myFunc` isn't wrapped up inside another function (which is what jsfiddle does when you use the onload option), then it should work fine. If it isn't then you need to try and post more of your code so we can see what might be stopping it working

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jquery for DOM traversal, you could do the following:

```
 $('#<%= button1.ClientID %>').on('click', function() {
      $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

Comment: sure, is there a way to do that in JavaScript

Comment: I would say then that @Rhumborl answer should work for you then

Comment: Just that it (the relevant part, aka function) is identical to the op's code.. I'm wondering what the OP's question is..

Comment: yep you are correct, I tested it from within the run code snippet option and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the function the right way, you should use braces:

```
onClick="myFunc()"
```